# How do you calculate the biggest box around a shape?

Tags: trigonometry

If you're given a 4-sided shape, how to you calculate the biggest* possible square/rectangle that will be needed to surround it no matter what orientation the shape is.

*biggest - by biggest, I mean the largest box to connect to all corners of the shape, no matter of it's orientation.

To help you understand my bad description, I have done this doodle:

[image]

I'm tried to calculate it using Pythagorean theorem, but I guess I went wrong.
Any advice or psuedocode would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the smallest box around a shape?

Comment: Oops... Yes I did. I've updated it. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Not to keep you going back and forth but… are you sure you meant the smallest? The one you have drawn actually looks like the *largest*, with the restriction that the vertices of the inner object must be in the edges of the square. The smallest would actually be just the square itself. Maybe you can see that by "rotating" the outer square in your figure above, you will get something smaller.

Comment: Very true. I guess I do mean the biggest; I'm trying to calculate the dashed shape (square or rect) around the one labelled `x/y`. Sorry, I got confused there. Now updating again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to find the diameter of the shape-the longest distance between two points of it.  Then make a square that is that diameter in both directions, because the diameter can be oriented either way.  For a rectangle, that is easy-just the length of the diagonal.  For more complicated shapes, you may have to scan the whole perimeter looking for the diameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's just confirmed what I have just done. Using the `X` and `Y` values of a square/rectangle, I used pythagoras to calculate the diagonal and constructed a square with sides equal to the diagonal.

Comment: I assumed that the bounding rectangle needs to be axis aligned.  You didn't say that, but saying that it has to work for all orientations seems to imply it.

Comment: Yes I think so. However, the way I've done it (using `sqrt(x^2+y^2)` provides the diameter of a bounding circle; the diameter is the value I used to create the bounding rect centered about the circle, so the two shapes are free to rotate without the inner coming outside of the outer, if that makes sense.

Comment: It is more subtle than that.  An equilateral triangle of side $d$ doesn't fit in a circle of diameter $d$.  It does fit in a $d \times d$ square in any orientation.